# Save resulting dict from api into db - psycopg2

Tags: python, json, python-requests, psycopg2

I want to save an API response, on some table of my database, I'm using Postgres along with `psycopg2`.

This is my code:

```
import json
import requests
import psycopg2

def my_func():
    response = requests.get("https://path/to/api/")
    data = response.json()

    while data['next'] is not None:
        response = requests.get(data['next'])
        data = response.json()
        for item in data['results']:
            try:
                connection = psycopg2.connect(user="user",
                                          password="user",
                                          host="127.0.0.1",
                                          port="5432",
                                          database="mydb")
                cursor = connection.cursor()

                postgres_insert_query = """ INSERT INTO table_items (NAME VALUES (%s)"""
                record_to_insert = print(item['name']) 
                cursor.execute(postgres_insert_query, record_to_insert)
                connection.commit()
                count = cursor.rowcount
                print (count, "success")
            except (Exception, psycopg2.Error) as error :
                if(connection):
                    print("error", error)
            finally:
                if(connection):
                    cursor.close()
                    connection.close()

my_func()
```

I mean, I just wanted to sort of "print" all the resulting data from my `request` into the db, is there a way to accomplish this?

I'm a bit confused as You can see, I mean, what could be some "print" equivalent to achieve this?

I mean, I just want to save from the API response, the `name` field, into the database table. Or actually `INSERT` that, I guess `psycopg2` has some sort of function for this circumstance?

Any example You could provide?

**EDIT**

Sorry, I forgot, if I run this code it will throw this:

```
PostgreSQL connection is closed
A particular name
Failed to insert record into table_items table syntax error at or near "VALUES"
LINE 1:  INSERT INTO table_items (NAME VALUES (%s)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues here. I'm not sure what the API is or what it is returning, but I will make some assumptions and suggestions based on those.

There is a syntax error in your query, it is missing a `)` it should be:
`postgres_insert_query = 'INSERT INTO table_items (NAME) VALUES (%s)'
(I'm also assuming that`NAME` is a real column in your database).

Even with this correction, you will have a problem since:
`record_to_insert = print(item['name'])` will set `record_to_insert` to `None`. The return value of the `print` function is always `None`. The line should instead be:

```
record_to_insert = item['name']
```

(assuming the key `name` in the dict `item` is actually the field you're looking for)

I believe calls to `execute` must pass replacements as a tuple so the line: `cursor.execute(postgres_insert_query, record_to_insert)` should be:

```
cursor.execute(postgres_insert_query, (record_to_insert,))
```